# AWK seperates Lines with capitals and non-capital letters with a semicolon, if there is no semicolon

Tags: awk, sed, delimiter

I have this converted dictionary to use in Pure Data. It consists of a series of 3 things: the word, how to pronounce it, and a semicolon to finish. In the converted dictionary, some semicolons are missing, so I want AWK to find the missings and put semicolons for me. I used delimiters before, but this one is difficult for me, so any help will be appreciated. See the text file: the first 3 are good, the last three are wrong, there is a semicolon missing at the end. I think the AWK delimiter will be between non-capital letters and capital letters, and the action is to put a semicolon if there is no semicolon already. How can I put this in AWK code?

```
ELFKIN
Elf
kin;
ELFLAND
Elf
land
;
ELFLOCK
Elf
lock
;
ELGIN
El
gin
ELICIT
E
lic
it
ELICIT
E
lic
it
```

I used some Delimiters before, but i do not know how to specify between in AWK.
So the Delimiter is non-capital letters and Capital letters, and put a semicolon there.
so some code would look like this
awk 'length($0)>1 && line with All capitals put semicolon before this line'
or
awk 'line with non-capitals if Next line is Capitals put semicolon after line
I have tryed this

```
awk 'length($0>1) && /[:^, upper:]/{l=l";"}NR>1{print l}{l=$0}END{print l}' file2
```

This is not good working.

Or am i pointing is the wrong direction.

Comment: Please edit question and add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I added an AWK code i am trying, but did not work. And btw the original file is all lines underneath each other.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus for editing my text. I now i have some answers AWK etc. are great

Comment: @Dianderocker as [@Cyrus requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78030709/awk-seperates-lines-with-capitals-and-non-capital-letters-with-a-semicolon-if-t#comment137563634_78030709) please add your desired output.

Comment: `length($0>1)` will always return `1` as it's getting the length of the output of the comparison `$0>1` which is either 1 or 0. Never name a variable `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code. `[:^, upper:]` is a bracket expression containing the set of characters `: ^ , <blank> u p e r`. I think you meant `[^, [:upper:]]` which means "not a comma, blank, or upper case letter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
ELFKIN
Elf
kin;
ELFLAND
Elf
land
;
ELFLOCK
Elf
lock
;
ELGIN
El
gin
ELICIT
E
lic
it
ELICIT
E
lic
it
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{print gensub(/([[:lower:]])\n([[:upper:]])/,"\\1;\n\\2","g")}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
ELFKIN
Elf
kin;
ELFLAND
Elf
land
;
ELFLOCK
Elf
lock
;
ELGIN
El
gin;
ELICIT
E
lic
it;
ELICIT
E
lic
it
```

Explanation: setting `RS` to empty string engage paragraph mode, as `file.txt` has not blank line, it is treated as 1 row. Then I use [`gensub` string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to replace all (`g` like globally) occurences of lowercase letter followed by newline followed by uppercase letter by 1st of that letters followed by semicolon followed by newline followed by 2nd letter.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: If you include the `\n` in the second capture group `/([[:lower:]])(\n[[:upper:]])/` then you don't need to add it again in the replacement, `"\\1;\n\\2"`, you can just use `"\\1;\\2"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    {
        if ( /^[[:upper:]]{2,}$/ && needs_terminator )
            print ";"
        print
        needs_terminator = !/;/
    }
    END {
        if (needs_terminator)
            print ";"
    }
' file
```

With your data, gives:

```
ELFKIN
Elf
kin;
ELFLAND
Elf
land
;
ELFLOCK
Elf
lock
;
ELGIN
El
gin
;
ELICIT
E
lic
it
;
ELICIT
E
lic
it
;
```

Comment: I thought it was working great looking at your data but when i process it myself it does nothing except that it gives a ; at the end of the text. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: It works with the data in your question but It won't work, for example, if your actual data contains DOS line endings (`\r` is not an upper case letter - nor is any other whitespace)

Comment: `{2,}` does not work with some versions of awk. An alternative regex could be: `/^[[:upper:]][[:upper:]]+$/`

Answer (score 2):

This, using any POSIX awk, may be what you're trying to do but without expected output in the question, it's a guess:

```
$ awk '/^[[:upper:]]/ && (prev ~ /[[:lower:]]$/){print ";"} {print; prev=$0}' file
ELFKIN
Elf
kin;
ELFLAND
Elf
land
;
ELFLOCK
Elf
lock
;
ELGIN
El
gin
;
ELICIT
E
lic
it
;
ELICIT
E
lic
it
```

Note that, unlike some other solutions, the above does not require the whole input file to be read into memory and so will work no matter how large your input is.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/^;$/d;h
         :a;p;n;/.+;$/{p;b};x;G;s/^(.+)(.*)\n\1$/\2/i;/^$/{x;s/$/;/p;b};x;ba' file
```

This solution compares the first word of a set with subsequent words until all subsequent words are matched to the first and if need be appends a `;`.

N.B. This alters the original file, deleting any single lines containing only a `;`. Also this does not rely only on uppercase words to signify the beginning of a word set.

A couple of alternatives:

```
sed -E '/^;$/d;h
        :a;n;x;G;s/^(.+)(.*)\n\1;?$/\2/i;/^;?$/{x;s/;?$/\n;/;b};x;ba' file
```

Or just using the uppercaseness of the first word of a set:

```
sed -E '$!N;${s/;?$/;/;b};/\n[[:upper:]]{2,}/!{P;D};s/;?\n/;\n/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `shell` and `sed`, the regexes are easy to understand, they are basic:

```
echo $(< file) |
     sed -E 's/ *;? *\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/;\1/g; s/;//; s/ +/\n/g; s/;/\n;\n/g'
```

`echo $(< file)` is a little hack taking advantage of bash's [*word splitting*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) to split the content of file on one line to be easylly processed by `sed`.

Yields:

```
ELFKIN
Elf
kin
;
ELFLAND
Elf
land
;
ELFLOCK
Elf
lock
;
ELGIN
El
gin
;
ELICIT
E
lic
it
;
ELICIT
E
lic
it
```

Comment: the problem statement appears to want semicolon as terminator rather than as separator

Comment: The way to thanks here, is voting up/accepting answer :)

Comment: The construct of `echo $(< file)` is great for word splitting but unfortunately globs and all other [expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) are performed as well. This will destroy the input potentially. See edit in my post for example...

Comment: You could use `tr '\n' ' ' < file` instead of `echo $(< file)` to avoid the globbing issues that @dawg mentioned, assuming your `sed` can process input that doesn't have a terminating newline.

Comment: Hello Gilles, thanks for the help, your code does the job well, except i did not realize there where - in words, like in FIDDLE-SHAPED           and these words gets split in 2 by the code commands, and that is not good for me, for the dictionary i want to use

Answer (score -1):

You state *I think the AWK delimiter will be between non-capital letters and capital letters, and the action is to put a semicolon if there is no semicolon already.*

You can express that in a PCRE regex using a lookback for a lowercase letter with a lookforward for a line ending and uppercase letter.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/2CuJ87/1)

To do that in the shell, you can use this Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(?<=[a-z])(?=\R[A-Z])/;/g' file
```

Prints:

```
ELFKIN
Elf
kin;
ELFLAND
Elf
land
;
ELFLOCK
Elf
lock
;
ELGIN
El
gin;
ELICIT
E
lic
it;
ELICIT
E
lic
it
```

How does this work?

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(?<=[a-z])(?=\R[A-Z])/;/g' file 
       ^                                          'gulp' mode - read as one string
            ^                                     autoprint mode
                ^                                 make a substitution
```

If you want a line separator between the blocks (you show both `\n;` and `;` as delimiters...) just add `\n` to the substitution.

You can also use Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'puts $<.read.gsub(/(?<=[a-z])(?=\R[A-Z])/,";")' file
# same output
```

---

Note: The accepted answer has potentially bad side effects. Suppose you have:

```
$  ls -1
File1
File2
File3
file
```

And suppose that `file` has the contents:

```
$ cat file
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3 *
Line 4
```

Now try the accepted answers 'trick' for word splitting:

```
$ echo $(< file)
Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 File1 File2 File3 file Line 4
```

You can see that the contents of the file not only are subject the word splitting (which was the intent) but all other shell [expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) are performed as well -- in this case the `*` expanded to the CWD contents and destroyed the file input...

Comment: thanks, the perl script i used and works great